# Qt: either signal won't send, or slot is not called

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

I have two Qt classes implied in this problem: `MainWindow` and `otaManager`.

I want to send a signal from `otaManager` and let `MainWindow` call a slot when it does.

Here's `MainWindow.h` (https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/1d48a6d85ee5b0a4db86c1d9f49510d0d923b297/mainwindow.h#L104):

```
private slots:
    void openUpdateDialogOTA(bool open);
    ...

private:
    ...
    otaManager *otaManagerWindow;
```

`MainWindow.cpp` (https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/1d48a6d85ee5b0a4db86c1d9f49510d0d923b297/mainwindow.cpp#L979-L993):

```
...
void MainWindow::openUpdateDialogOTA(bool open) {
    if(open == true) {
        global::otaUpdate::isUpdateOta = true;
        openUpdateDialog();
    }
    else {
        ;
    }
}


void MainWindow::launchOtaUpdater() {
    otaManagerWindow = new otaManager(this);
    connect(otaManagerWindow, SIGNAL(canOtaUpdate(bool)), SLOT(openUpdateDialogOTA(bool)));
    otaManagerWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
}
```

`otaManager.h` (https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/1d48a6d85ee5b0a4db86c1d9f49510d0d923b297/otamanager.h#L21-L22):

```
...
signals:
    void canOtaUpdate(bool yesno);
...
```

`otaManager.cpp` (https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/1d48a6d85ee5b0a4db86c1d9f49510d0d923b297/otamanager.cpp#L15-L30):

```
        ...
        if(global::otaUpdate::downloadOta != true) {
            string_writeconfig("/opt/ibxd", "ota_update_check\n");
            while(true) {
                if(QFile::exists("/run/can_ota_update") == true) {
                    if(checkconfig("/run/can_ota_update") == true) {
                        emit canOtaUpdate(true);
                        qDebug() << "OTA update is available!";
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        emit canOtaUpdate(false);
                        qDebug() << "No OTA update available.";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
       ...
```

When compiled and running, the program passes all the conditions in otaManager and outputs the "OTA update is available!" message via a QDebug call.

Though, either the slot is not being called by MainWindow when receiving the signal or it is not being sent, because the `openUpdateDialogOTA` function in MainWindow, even when I put some QDebug calls to see if it was even launched, does not output nor do anything.

I'm quite puzzled by all this because I did it this way for other classes in my project and it worked just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the otaManagerWindow isn't being closed before the signal is received in your MainWindow? Did you try commenting out `otaManagerWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);`?

Comment: I commented the `otaManager::close()` call farther in the class, and it didn't work.
And I just tried what you said and no effect at all either.

Comment: I can't see the reason at the moment. You said you did verify that `openUpdateDialogOTA()` was definitely not called by putting qDebug() at the top of that function correct?

Comment: Yes. I put a `qDebug() << "Got there"` at the top of it. When called from main thread and not from signal, it works.
I also tried another test signal/slot pair and nothing happened either.

Comment: did you try to connect SIGNAL with SLOT in constructor of `MainWindow` class?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: did you try to write this `connect(otaManagerWindow, &otaManager::canOtaUpdate, this, &MainWindow::openUpdateDialogOTA);` in constructor of MainWindow class?

Comment: Yes, not working

Answer (score 0):

You forget about receiver object:

```
connect(otaManagerWindow, SIGNAL(canOtaUpdate(bool)), SLOT(openUpdateDialogOTA(bool)));
```

Try to use new style for connect method:

```
connect(a, &A::OnSignal, b, &B::OnSlot);
```

Comment: You mean this? `connect(otaManagerWindow, &otaManager::canOtaUpdate, this, &MainWindow::openUpdateDialogOTA);` It doesn't work either.

Comment: Try to delete build folder.

Comment: Did you try to call your `signal` like a method without `emit`?

Comment: No, what would that do?

Comment: `emit` is syntactic sugar. maybe it is bad in your case. just I try to think.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `while(true)` loop was the culprit. I still don't know why, and I wonder if it is even normal. I switched to a QTimer implementation instead, as you can see here: https://github.com/Kobo-InkBox/inkbox/blob/1f539e6bf3020d2a4069295133e0cd470efb8ca9/otamanager.cpp

The signals are now sent without any issue.